# Property 'navHeight' does not exist on type 'Theme'? Using MUI v5 syntax with Typescript and custom props theme.ts file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

Using `theme.palette.primary.main` works, but when I try to use MUI with declared new props in the Interface inside the theme.ts file (recommended by the MUI docs) I get the error from the posted question. I dont know what else to do besides everything I tried (import Interface, MUI v4 syntax, etc). This is my code:

```
import {styled} from "@mui/material/styles";
import {Box, Container, Grid, NativeSelect} from "@mui/material";
//import CustomLink from "../custom-link/custom-link.component";

export const Background = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
  position: "fixed",
  zIndex: "10",
  height: theme.navHeight,
  width: "100%",
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
  boxShadow: "0 7px 4px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
}));
```

My theme component:

```
import React from "react";
import {ThemeProvider} from "@mui/material/styles";
import useMediaQuery from "@mui/material/useMediaQuery";
import theme from ".";

interface ThemeProps {
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}

function Theme({children}: ThemeProps): JSX.Element {
  const isMd = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("md"), {
    defaultMatches: true,
  });

  let navHeight = theme.navHeightDesktop;
  let sectionPadding = theme.sectionPadding;

  if (isMd) {
    sectionPadding = "padding-bottom: 5rem;";
  } else {
    navHeight = theme.navHeightMobile;
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={{...theme, navHeight, sectionPadding}}>
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default Theme;
```

My theme.ts file:

```
import {createTheme} from "@mui/material/styles";

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Theme {
    navHeightDesktop: string;
    navHeightMobile: string;
    sectionPadding: string;
    fonts: object;
    layout: object;
    tertiary?: {
      main: React.CSSProperties["color"];
    };
  }

  interface ThemeOptions {
    navHeightDesktop: string;
    navHeightMobile: string;
    sectionPadding: string;
    fonts: object;
    layout: object;
    tertiary?: {
      main: React.CSSProperties["color"];
    };
  }
}

const theme = createTheme({
  navHeightDesktop: "80px",
  navHeightMobile: "50px",
  sectionPadding: "padding-bottom: 2.5em;",
  fonts: {
    primary: "Roboto, sans-serif",
    secondary: "Roboto, sans-serif",
  },
  layout: {
    contentWidth: 1236,
  },
  palette: {
    primary: {
      // contrastText: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)",
      main: "#000",
    },
    secondary: {
      // contrastText: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)",
      main: "#fff",
      light: "#FAFAFA",
    },
    text: {
      primary: "#fff",
      secondary: "#fff",
      disabled: "#10355A",
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: `"Roboto", "Open Sans", "Arial", sans-serif`,
  },
  shadows: [
    "none",
    "0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 3px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 4px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 7px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 2px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 5px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 8px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 3px 14px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 5px 6px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 9px 12px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 3px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 6px 6px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 10px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 4px 18px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 6px 7px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 11px 15px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 4px 20px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 7px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 12px 17px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 5px 22px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 7px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 13px 19px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 5px 24px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 7px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 14px 21px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 5px 26px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 8px 9px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 15px 22px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 6px 28px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 8px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 16px 24px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 6px 30px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 8px 11px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 17px 26px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 6px 32px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 9px 11px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 18px 28px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 7px 34px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 9px 12px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 19px 29px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 7px 36px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 20px 31px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 8px 38px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 21px 33px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 8px 40px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 10px 14px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 22px 35px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 8px 42px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 11px 14px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 23px 36px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 9px 44px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    "0px 11px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 24px 38px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 9px 46px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
  ],
  transitions: {
    easing: {
      easeInOut: "cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)",
      easeOut: "cubic-bezier(0.0, 0, 0.2, 1)",
      easeIn: "cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1)",
      sharp: "cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 1)",
    },
    duration: {
      shortest: 150,
      shorter: 200,
      short: 250,
      standard: 300,
      complex: 375,
      enteringScreen: 225,
      leavingScreen: 195,
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `navHeight` is not define in the `Theme` interface, use the following code and it should works

```
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Theme {
    navHeight: string;
    navHeightDesktop: string;
    navHeightMobile: string;
    sectionPadding: string;
    fonts: object;
    layout: object;
    tertiary?: {
      main: React.CSSProperties["color"];
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just noticed I wasnt supposed to used that naming in the styles file with your example.